# JMeter - How can I add curly braces in extracted cookie value?

Tags: cookies, jmeter, curly-braces

I have something like below:

```
POST data:
["Authenticator - onLogin",{"quid":"{585FF452-396F-41FA-828A-1889254CE3D3}"}]

Cookie Data:
kd_rideplan=16290238~jv=59~id=18c09c49c920156613; QUID=585FF452-396F-41FA-828A-1889254CE3D3; appEnvOverride=%7B%22env%22%3A%22integration1%22%7D
```

585FF452-396F-41FA-828A-1889254CE3D3 was captured using JSON Extractor c_QUID.
On the POST data I can simply add extra curly braces as below
["Authenticator - onLogin",{"quid":"{${c_QUID}}"}] to have the curly braces around the captured value.

But, how can I have similar curly braces added around 585FF452-396F-41FA-828A-1889254CE3D3 on Cookie Data? Or, is there a way for JSON Extractor to capture with the curly braces which would also solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on extraction bit without seeing the response and your JSON Extractor configuration, theoretically it should be possible, for sure it is with the [JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor).

With regards to the "Cookie Data" - you can play the same trick, if you put your `c_QUID` variable surrounded by the curly braces in the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) - it will send the cookie value with the braces.

Demo:

[image]

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)